# How to copy word length in to clipboard?

Tags: neovim

i have a few words and need to copy word length in to clipboard.

Tried :!wc or g and Gv but don't work

Answer (score 1):

If your Vim has:

- `:help wordcount()`
- and clipboard support (`:echo has('clipboard')` echoes `1`),

you could create a custom mapping:

```
xnoremap <key> <Cmd>let @+ = wordcount().visual_words<CR>
```

that you would use like this:

```
v{motion}<key>
```

where you:

1. visually select your words,
2. and press `<key>`.

See `:help <Cmd>` and `:help wordcount()`.

Comment: For me don't work. 
I have wordcount(), <Cmd>, has('clipboard') === 1
Using neovim 0.9

My key
`<C-t> <Cmd>let @+ = wordcount().visual_words<CR>`

Select one word and press C-t, and nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Finded solution.
Copy word to clipboard.
And map copy length to clipboard +

```
nmap <C-t> :let @+ = len(@+)<CR>
```